# Creating widgets based on a list

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a parameter n, and i have to create n textfields and listen to them, and capture the value of all these fields. 
Say I have to perform calculations on them. How do I achieve this? I tried to combine loops with widgets but I get lots of errors.

When I used a separate function to return a list of widgets for column's children property, it throws an error stating `type int is not a subtype of type string of source`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

generate a list from your `d` parameter and then generate a list of text field and text editing contotlers from that list

```
createTexttextfields (int d){
    var textEditingControllers = <TextEditingController>[];

    var textFields = <TextField>[];
    var list = new List<int>.generate(d, (i) =>i + 1 );
    print(list);

    list.forEach((i) {
      var textEditingController = new TextEditingController(text: "test $i");
      textEditingControllers.add(textEditingController);
      return textFields.add(new TextField(controller: textEditingController));
    });
    return textFields;
}
```

and then use this function in the children property of your widget for example the column widget

```
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
  body: new Column(
  children: createTexttextfields(6),
  ),
);
```

But if you want to access them you can't do that by a function you must create them as variables

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var d=5;//the number of text fields 
    var textEditingControllers = <TextEditingController>[];
    var textFields = <TextField>[];
    var list = new List<int>.generate(d, (i) =>i + 1 );
    list.forEach((i) {
      var textEditingController = new TextEditingController(text: "test $i");
      textEditingControllers.add(textEditingController);
      return textFields.add(new TextField(controller: textEditingController));
    });

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Column(
      children: textFields),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          //clear the text in the second TextEditingController
          textEditingControllers[1].clear(); 
        } ,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[Full Example](https://gist.github.com/rahichesoft/afc9e3308a73d8fda713560c82e2d352)

Comment: Thanks bro, that works and i used a Listview instead of enable scrolling, but one more doubt, am i supposed to handle the input inside the function?

Comment: if you want to handle text input convert this function into fields inside your class

Answer (score 3):

```
return Container(
      height: 50,
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 60,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 20.0,
              height: 20.0,
              child: MaterialButton(
                color:AppTheme.colorDark,
                colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                onPressed: () => print(index),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                child:  Text('$index'),
              ),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Very generic example of creating a `List<Widget>` from a List:

```
  Widget _buildColumn() {
    
    var stringList = ["a", "b", "c"];

    // Create a List<Text> (or List<MyWidget>) using each String from stringList
    var textList = stringList.map<Text>((s) => Text(s)).toList();
   
    // use that list however you want!
    return Column(children: textList);
 
  }
```

Looks like this :

[image: screenshot]