# flutter create widgets at run time

Tags: flutter

I want to create forms in flutter. But the widgets that will be used in the form are not predefined. Which widgets to use will be determined by json response. Is there any way in flutter to create widgets at runtime and manage their state.

The json will look something like below

```
{  
  id:1,
  Answer: "Click on Register button so that we can get you started",
  Widget:[  
      "google OAuth"
  ],
  ReplyUrl:"www.example.com/api"
}
{
  id:2,
  Widget: [  
     {  
       "Question":"What is your name ?",
       "Type":"text",
       "VariableName":"Onboarding_Name"
     },
     {  
         "Question":"What is your birth date ?",
         "Type":"date",
         "VariableName":"Onboarding_BirthDate"
     }
   ],
   ReplyUrl:"www.example.com/api"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that your model class is `Question` and you want to make a widget for each `Question` you have in your list:

```
List<Question> Questions;
```

You simply map them :

```
 Questions.map((question) {
      if question.type == date {
        return DateQuestionWidget(question.title);
      } else if question.type == text {
        return TextQuestionWidget(question.title);
      }
     }
   );
```

Comment: But each response will ask to create different types of widgets like slider, date etc. How to handle that and how to manage state of such dynamically created widgets. Also the input type for each question will be different

Comment: yes you can use condition to create your widgets . i updated my answer

Comment: What about state ? Because I want to post all those values to the server

Comment: make sure that every widget will manage it's own internal state and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903696/creating-widgets-based-on-a-list/50903974#50903974) contains more info about state